# click button select image display image into ImageView

Tags: android, android-layout

My App Consist of 5 buttons ((2) Cancel buttons) , ((2) browse buttons), and "Next" button for moving to next Activity , (2)Image-views.
So what i need to implement is when click to browse, select in image from gallery than display it on an Image View , when press Cancel button, cancel the Image from the Image View.

same for anther browse button, on click , select an image from gallery , display on the second Image View , when press cancel button, remove the Image from the Second Image View.

When click Next button, pass the 2 images from current Activity to the Next Activity. any help please.

**Attachment_class.java**

```
public class Attachment_class extends AppCompatActivity {

ImageView img_One;
Button btn_Browse_Image_One;
Button btn_Cancel_Image_One;

ImageView img_Two;
Button btn_Browse_Image_Two;
Button btn_Cancel_Image_Two;

Button Next;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.attachment);

    img_One = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImgView_One);
    btn_Browse_Image_One = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Broswe_image_one);
    btn_Cancel_Image_One = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Cancel_ImgView_One);


    img_Two = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImgView_Two);
    btn_Browse_Image_Two = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Broswe_image_two);
    btn_Cancel_Image_Two = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Cancel_ImgView_Two);

    Next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Next_Attch_Btn);

}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Uri imageUri;

btn_Browse_Image_One.setOnClickListener(this);  
btn_Cancel_Image_One.setOnClickListener(this);  
Next.setOnClickListener(this);

@Override
public void onClick(View view)
{
int id = view.getId();

if (id == R.id.Broswe_image_one)
{
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(intent, 101);
}

if (id == R.id.Cancel_ImgView_One)
{
   img_One.setImageDrawable(null);
}

if (id == R.id.Next_Attch_Btn)
{
   if(imageUri != null)
   {
      Intent intent = new Intent(Attachment_class.this, NextActivity.class);                
      intent.putExtra("imageUri", imageUri.toString());
      startActivity(intent);

      or

      Intent intent = new Intent(Attachment_class.this, NextActivity.class);
      Bitmap bitmap;  // take from img view 
      ByteArrayOutputStream bs = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50, bs);
      intent.putExtra("byteArray", _bs.toByteArray());
      startActivity(intent);
   }
   else
   {
        Log.i("ImageError","Image not selected"); 
   }
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, final Intent data)
{ 
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == 101 && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
         Uri uri = data.getData();
         imageUri = uri;

         Picasso.get().load(uri).into(img_One);

         // Add the recent dependency for Picasso
    }
}
```

And receive intent in another activity as

```
Uri myUri = Uri.parse(intent.getString("imageUri"));
```

Similarly implement for second button. I hope this helps.

Comment: thanks brother but how can i pass the image if its not null to onther activity as a bitmap?

Comment: I have modified. So you can upvote and accept the answer

Comment: am getting an error in this code-> if (id == btn_Cancel_Image_One) Operator == cannot be applied to "int"

Comment: uri = data.getData();
                imageUri = uri; what type of data is the uri??

Comment: cannot resolve method "With"  -->Picasso.with(this).load(uri).fit().centerCrop().into(img_One);

Comment: bro when its open the gallery part the gallery rotating to land scape why?

Comment: Use can add another question for this in stackOverflow by completely describing your problem. But possible reason can be that your landscape mode may be turned on.

Comment: brother can i Contact you via e-mail?